# un able to get the value of template field text box in a custom method in update event in grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the value of my `txtCustomerName` textbox (template field) in code behind, however when i run my code,i am getting a null `reference exception`

**aspx code**

```
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:Label ID="lblCusomerName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustomerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CustomerName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

```
       protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
              //  int rowindex = gridviewQuoteDetails.SelectedRow

                string Company = ((TextBox)gridviewQuoteDetails.SelectedRow.FindControl("txtCustomerName")).Text;
    }
```

Comment: this will help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating(v=vs.110).aspx. you might be using wrong event.

Comment: the event is already has been written...so i have to write in that same event only